# Using LINQ instead of using for-each loop

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following code. How to convert this into a LINQ? Any one please help me.

In the below code 'powd' contains the db values and purchaseOrderUpdateRequest contains data submitted by user.

```
bool hasUpdate;

foreach (var item in purchaseOrderUpdateRequest.Lines)
{
    var line = powd.PurchaseOrderLines.Single(p => p.ItemNumber ==  item.ItemNumber);
    decimal quantityToReceive = item.QuantityReceived - line.QuantityReceivedToDate;

    if (quantityToReceive > 0)
    {
        hasUpdate =true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So all you're trying to work out is whether any item has an update? That's just:

```
var hasUpdate = purchaseOrder.UpdateRequest.Lines.Any(item =>
     item.QuantityReceived < powd.PuchaseOrderLines
                                 .Single(p => p.ItemNumber == item.ItemNumber)
                                 .QuantityReceivedToDate)
```

I've changed the comparison to just use a direct `<` rather than a subtraction and a comparison with 0, but this should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should do the same and might be easier to read:

```
   var quantities = (from item in purchaseOrderUpdateRequest.Lines
                     from item2 in powd.PurchaseOrderLines
                     where item.ItemNumber == item2.ItemNumber
                     select item.QuantityReceived - item2.QuantityReceivedToDate);
   hasUpdate = quantities.Any(quantityToReceive => (decimal) quantityToReceive > 0);
```